# url rewrite recursively

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite url from www.xxx.com/test.com to www.xxx.com/my.php?d=test.com
using the following directive:

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteRule ^((.+)\.(.+))$ my.php?d=$1
```

this is not working, for example, the url is www.xxx.com/test.com
it seems like it gets rewrite to www.xxx.com/my.php?d=test.com
then gets rewrite to www.xx.com/my.php?d=my.php or something like that.  does this mean the pattern is getting applied recursively??
how do I fix the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod rewrite will run a URI through the rewrite engine over and over until the URI is the same before and after it goes through the rewrite engine. This is what's happening:

1. URI is **test.com**
2. rule `^((.+)\.(.+))$` matches, URI rewritten to **my.php** (with some query string *d* = *test.com*)
3. compare: **test.com** is not the same as **my.php**, run the URI back through the rewrite engine
4. URI is **my.php**
5. rule `^((.+)\.(.+))$` matches, URI rewritten to **my.php** (with some query string *d* = *my.php*)
6. compare: **my.php** is the same as **my.php**, before and after URI match, stop writing

Your result is `/my.php?d=my.php`

You need to add a condition so my.php doesn't get the rule applied. Add this before your rewriterule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my.php
```

Comment: his problem is similar to mine, by in my case, "my.php" is called dynamically. so Apache does not know what file will be called before the rule is applied. 

`RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*)?$ .../$1/index.php?params=$2 [NC,L]` is what I got. any ideas how to make a condition that will allow apache to redirect only once?!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+)$ my.php?d=$1.$2
```

The effect is not that the rule is applied recursively (that doesn't happen), it simply didn't match.

BTW, if you want to make the engine stop at a specific line, you can add [L].

An easy way to test rewrite rule is [this website](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: that website, btw, won't catch recursive problems.  I have the same issue, and it's fine with mine