# Recursive redirection in htaccess URL rewriting (mod_rewrite in Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In the root folder of my project there are several other folders I am calling "apps". The path to one of these apps is something like: `/root_folder/myapp/...`

There are actually a dozen apps like this. So I want my project to be using friendly URLs, and to achieve that I am using the apache module **mod_rewrite**.

I added the following rule to my .htaccess (that is in root_folder, just so you to know) `RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*)?$ myDomain.com/$1/index.php?params=$2 [NC,L]`

So an URL such as mydomain/myApp/param/value/param2/value would be translated to mydomain/myApp/index.php?params=value/param2/value

I performed some tests and saw it working until I added the $1 to refer to the app folder (have a look: the_path_to_my_root_folder_here/**$1**/index.php?params=$2)
 The path to one of these apps is something like: `/root_folder/myapp/...**
It is generating an URL like: myDomain.com/myApp/index.php?params=index.php

Well I thought it would be a recursion issue. So it seems that Apache will try another redirection after the first is performed, and then it will generate an URL like that

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953895/url-rewrite-recursively/8957377) in Stack Overflow
The problem with the answer is that it`s assuming I know when to stop.

Do you know how to make this second redirection to stop?

I am trying the following rule now
`RewriteRule myDomain.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.*)$/ myDomain.com/$1/index.php?params=$2 [NC,L]`, but it's not working properly. It is only matching the regex, if I do not pass parameters after the app name. so when I try myDomain.com/user/ it works (not receiving parameters), and fails when I try myDomain.com/user/products/1000/, for example. Instead of rewriting/redirecting, it is trying to find a folder *products* inside *user* and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rewrite rule to something that will match the input url but not your output url. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([a-z]+)\/(.+)$ /$1/index.php?params=$2/$3
```

Comment: hey Stephanie! it works ok, but not sure what you mean with $2 and $3. what if I am passing 2 or 3 'arguments', like **http://mydomain.com/list/user/1000/limit/20** in this URL I am calling the app 'list' and passing **user/1000/limit/20** as parameter to be split and parsed in the script. The best idea would be separate it only in two, like **app&params** and then call app passing params. any ideas?

Comment: Instead of capturing all your parameters together, you split them up so that $2 will capture your first paramater name and $3 will capture the first parameter value plus any other parameters you might have. This way your rewrite rule is more specific and will not end up matching your index.php url again.

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `DOCUMET_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php?params=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Unable to understand what you mean by `the_path_to_my_root_folder_here`

Comment: I meant my root folder URL. I will edit my original post

Comment: so I tried this and it actually made things worse. now the recursion is not stoping. it is filling the whole address bar with **&params=index.php**

Comment: Can you tell what is location of `.htaccess` file?

Comment: the root is something like **myProjectName/www/**
so my .htaccess is in this 'www' folder. APPs are also inside www, like **myProjectName/www/myApp/**

Comment: ok thanks and the URL you're entering is this: `http://mydomain/myApp/param/value/param2/value2`? Also is there any .htaccess in `myProjectName/www/myApp/` also? Lastly if there are more rules in `myProjectName/www/.htacccess` then provide them in your question.

Comment: yes, http://mydomain/myApp/param/value/param2/value2 is an example of URL i want to use in this project. an appName and many parameters separeted by a / each one separeted from its value by a /
. no, there is no other .htaccess in the apps folders. I edited my Question by the way

Comment: So no other rewrite rules in this current .htaccess?

Comment: no, not at all. and no condition.
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule myDomain.com/([^/]*)/(.*)$ myDomain.com/$1/index.php?params=$2 [NC,L]`

is all I got right now

Comment: No you cannot have `myDomain.com` in `RewriteRule` since that doesn't match. Can you try the rule as I wrote above?

Comment: I am using myProjectName/www/ instead of myDomain.com. sorry that was just an example, I didn't know it would lead to an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43058/discussion-between-victor-ferreira-and-anubhava)

Comment: I have been waiting for your response on chat. Basically this rule `RewriteRule /projectName/www` isn't going to work. Leave me a comment when you get back.